# Does C# support an automatic return var type?

Tags: c#

This is a very simple question but googling is not finding me a definitive answer.

```
Int16 Method()
{
 ??? retVal = 123;
 return retVal;
}
```

Is there any keyword or special type I can use that says "this variable should be the method return type" i.e. in this case `???` would have type `Int16`?

I feel a language like C# *should/could* know what the return type is but I don't know how the language works under the hood. If the answer is "no" then I would love an explanation of the viability of such a language feature.

I do *not* want to make my return type generic. I do *not* want to infer the type of a `var` from an assigned value/expression. I want the return type fixed (in this case `Int16`) but a shorthand to use the return type automatically for a variable. It is along the lines of `typeof()`.

Comment: No, it does not. See https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1294

Comment: Is there a better way to describe than "automatic return var type" because part of my problem was not really knowing what term search for. `typeof` is a general feature but `_RetType` could conceivably be a more specific case

Comment: _I feel a language like C# should know what the return type is_ `123` could be a number of different types though...

Comment: @Fixation you have mis-read the question

Comment: @HimBromBeere it wouldn't be. I would get a compiler error just like if I did `Int16 x= 1.0 + 1.0`. That's the whole point. `???` would _be_ `Int16`

Comment: In your case it´s surely obvious, as you directly return `retVal`. But of course it could have been `return retVal + 1.0`. What would `retVal` be in that case? Why should it be `double`, when you pass `123`?

Comment: I guess I did mis-read it. Which makes me hope this won't become a new C# feature, hehe.

Comment: @HimBromBeere It wouldn't be `double`. The method's return type is specified in the method header - `Int16`, and it would be an error to return `retVal  + 1.0` without changing the method signature. OP seems to just want a type alias kind of thing that refers to the return type of the enclosing method.

Comment: The answer is a definitive "no, there isn't", reasons for this can be found in the link provided by canton7. I'd like to know why you would need such a feature, is there a real problem you try to solve or is this question just out of curiousity?

Comment: I can only think of very few cases where this would be useful. Are you sure this is not an XY problem?

Comment: @FeRaaC mainly I was curious given the existence of `var` in C# and `auto` in C++.

Comment: @canton7 what is the SO protocol when a definitive answer is given off-site? This seems to be the best answer but I cannot accept a comment as an answer :)

Comment: @Mr.Boy You haven't accepted any of my other answers to you >< If nobody's posted an answer which you think answers your question, then either don't accept anything, or if you've since learnt something which means you think you now know the answer to your own question, you can post your own answer and accept it.

Comment: @canton7 "any" is a peculiar word when there are only 2 I can see :) I hope you're not suggesting you are holding users to ransom unless they accept your answers!

Comment: @Mr.Boy I had a quick look at your question history as well :) Noone's holding anyone to ransom -- you've got the answer you wanted, as a comment. Just that it's less worth putting the effort into a proper descriptive answer if it has a low probability of being accepted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, C# doesn't support an automatic return var type. A "[var](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/implicitly-typed-local-variables)" keyword needs to know exactly type in line of code you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does, starting with C# 3

```
var i = 10; // Implicitly typed.
int i = 10; // Explicitly typed.
```

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var